# Extending LCR Algorithm from Single Ring to Ring of Rings Network for Leader Election

Tags: java

I've successfully implemented an asynchronous-start and terminating version of the LCR algorithm for leader election in a single ring network, as per my project's initial requirements. The algorithm allows processors to wake up at different rounds and terminates once a leader is elected, with all processors aware of the election result. My current implementation works as expected in a single ring setup.

Now, I need to extend this implementation to a more complex 'ring of rings' network topology, where each sub-ring (representing a subnetwork) is connected to form a larger ring (the main ring). The main ring should operate using the asynchronous-start variant of the LCR algorithm, while the sub-rings use the terminating LCR algorithm. The goal is to elect the processor with the maximum ID across the entire network as the leader, ensure all processors in the main ring are aware of the elected leader, and terminate all processors in the main ring upon completion.

Challenges & Expectations:

I'm grappling with the conceptual and implementation shift from a single ring to a ring of rings network. Specifically:

Interfacing Between Rings: How to effectively manage the interaction between sub-rings and the main ring, especially in terms of message passing and leader election propagation.

Ensuring Correctness and Performance: How to verify that the maximum ID is consistently elected across various network sizes and structures, and how to efficiently measure the rounds and message counts until termination.

I anticipate challenges in adapting the existing algorithm to support this hierarchical network structure without compromising on the efficiency and correctness of the leader election process.

**Current Implementation:**

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numProcessors = 5; // Total number of processors in the ring
        Ring ringNetwork = new Ring();

        // Initialise processors with unique IDs and start rounds
        for (int i = 0; i < numProcessors; i++) {
            int startRound = i + 1; // Example start rounds
            Processor processor = new Processor(i + 1, startRound);
            ringNetwork.addProcessor(processor);
        }

        // Start the leader election process
        ringNetwork.startElection();
        System.out.println("Leader elected: Processor ID " + ringNetwork.getElectedLeaderId());
    }
}
```

**Processor.java**

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Processor {
    private final int id;
    private final int startRound;
    private Processor clockwiseNeighbor;
    private final Queue<Integer> messageQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    private final AtomicBoolean isActive = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final AtomicBoolean hasElected = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private int leaderId = -1;

    public Processor(int id, int startRound) {
        this.id = id;
        this.startRound = startRound;
    }

    public void setClockwiseNeighbor(Processor neighbor) {
        this.clockwiseNeighbor = neighbor;
    }

    public void activate(int currentRound) {
        if (currentRound >= startRound && isActive.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            // Process any messages that were received before activation but not processed
            while (!messageQueue.isEmpty()) {
                processMessage(messageQueue.poll());
            }
            sendMessage(id); // Send initial message with own ID
        }
    }

    // Send a message to the clockwise neighbor
    private void sendMessage(int message) {
        if (clockwiseNeighbor != null) {
            clockwiseNeighbor.receiveMessage(message, isActive.get());
        }
    }
    
    // Receive a message from the counter-clockwise neighbor
    public void receiveMessage(int message, boolean senderActive) {
        if (senderActive) { // Only queue messages from active senders
            messageQueue.add(message);
        }
    }

    public void processMessages() {
        while (!messageQueue.isEmpty() && isActive.get()) {
            processMessage(messageQueue.poll());
        }
    }

    // Process the received message
    private void processMessage(int receivedId) {
        if (receivedId > id && !hasElected.get()) {
            sendMessage(receivedId);
        } else if (receivedId == id) {
            hasElected.set(true);
            leaderId = id; // Elect self and terminate
            System.out.println("Processor " + id + " elected as leader");
            // Propagate leader ID for others to terminate
            sendMessage(id);
        } else if (hasElected.get()) {
            // If this processor has already elected a leader, propagate the leader's ID
            sendMessage(leaderId);
        }
    }

    public void acknowledgeLeader(int leaderId) {
        if (!hasElected.get()) {
            this.leaderId = leaderId;
            hasElected.set(true);
            isActive.set(false); // Terminate after acknowledging the leader
            System.out.println("Processor " + id + " acknowledges leader " + leaderId);
        }
    }
    public boolean hasElected() {
        return hasElected.get();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getLeaderId() {
        return leaderId;
    }
}
```

**Ring.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Ring {
    private final List<Processor> processors = new ArrayList<>();
    private int electedLeaderId = -1;
    private int currentRound = 1;

    // Add a processor to the ring
    public void addProcessor(Processor processor) {
        if (!processors.isEmpty()) {
            processors.get(processors.size() - 1).setClockwiseNeighbor(processor);
        }
        processors.add(processor);
    }

    // Close the ring by connecting the last and first processors
    public void closeRing() {
        if (!processors.isEmpty()) {
            processors.get(processors.size() - 1).setClockwiseNeighbor(processors.get(0));
        }
    }

    public void startElection() {
        closeRing(); // Ensure the ring is closed before starting
        boolean electionInProgress = true;

        while (electionInProgress) {
            simulateRound();
            electionInProgress = checkElectionProgress();
        }
    }

    private void simulateRound() {
        processors.forEach(p -> p.activate(currentRound));
        processors.forEach(Processor::processMessages);

        currentRound++; // Increment round for next simulation
    }

    private boolean checkElectionProgress() {
        // Check if a leader has been elected and propagate the leader ID to all processors
        for (Processor p : processors) {
            if (p.hasElected() && electedLeaderId == -1) {
                electedLeaderId = p.getLeaderId();
                processors.forEach(proc -> proc.acknowledgeLeader(electedLeaderId));
                break;
            }
        }

        // Check if all processors have acknowledged the leader
        return processors.stream().anyMatch(proc -> !proc.hasElected());
    }

    public int getElectedLeaderId() {
        return electedLeaderId;
    }
}
```

Required Changes:

To adapt my project to a ring of rings network, I need insights on:

Algorithmic Adaptation: Strategies to extend the single ring LCR algorithm to support the ring of rings topology while maintaining asynchronous start and termination.

Implementation Guidance: Suggestions on managing the complexity of multiple interconnected rings and ensuring efficient message passing and leader election propagation.

Performance Evaluation: Advice on setting up simulations for networks of varying sizes and structures to validate the correctness of the algorithm and measure its performance.

Any guidance, insights, or references to similar implementations would be greatly appreciated as I navigate this complex extension of my project.